# On first click on my URL angular app is not navigating to the URL route

Tags: angularjs

I have URL like this:

```
 ui-sref="preview({ preview: file.dropbox_name,extension:file.type })"
```

And AngularJS script like this:

```
   .state('/Files', {
      url: "/Files",
      templateUrl: '/App/scripts/files.html'

    })

    .state('preview', {
        url: '/Files?preview?extension',
        templateUrl: '/App/scripts/views/filePreview.html',
        controller : 'FilesController'
      })
```

Once I click on a file for the first time URL change but not going there but when I click again then it go there? how can do it so that for the first click it take me to preview page? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a structure more like this:

```
.state('files', {
  url: "/Files",
  templateUrl: '/App/scripts/files.html',
  controller: 'FilesController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  params: {
    preview: null,
    extension: null
  }
})
.state('files.preview', {
  url: '/Files/preview/:extension',
  templateUrl: '/App/scripts/views/filePreview.html',
  controller : 'FilesPreviewController'
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

I presume 'files.preview' is a child state of 'files'. This also makes more sense when looking at the url structure you are using. You should also have separate controllers for separate states.

Comment: What would be a link to this second state then as from ducumentation it should be like this ui-sref=".preview " how can I pass the file to preview and extension?

Comment: This is Url  i have that point to that route ui-sref=".preview({ preview: file.dropbox_name,extension:file.type })" The problem now is that Files is not replaced by it's preview.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue by                                                            .state('preview', {
            url: '/Files/:preview/:extension',
            templateUrl: '/App/scripts/views/filePreview.html',
            controller : 'FilesController'
          })

Comment: Nice, glad it's fixed :)